# zipline installation error : failed building wheel for bcolz

Tags: python, pip, zipline, bcolz

I'm trying to install zipline on a virtual environment on mac os.

Python version = 3.6 / numpy, cython pre-installed

When I try `pip install zipline` on the virtual environment, I get the following error. (There are a lot of warnings printed out on the console, but I thought the warning below was key to my problem)

```
1 warning and 1 error generated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for bcolz
```

I've tried installing bcolz, but didn't seem to solve the problem. I'd appreciate solutions.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT :

The error code was so long that it went out of bound of the console. So here are some of the last lines of errors.

```
 31 warnings generated.
    In file included from bcolz/carray_ext.c:242:
    In file included from /Users/choehyeong-gyu/PycharmProjects/CubicHill/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
    In file included from /Users/choehyeong-gyu/PycharmProjects/CubicHill/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18:
    In file included from /Users/choehyeong-gyu/PycharmProjects/CubicHill/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1821:
    /Users/choehyeong-gyu/PycharmProjects/CubicHill/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by "          "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
    #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
     ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:43580:32: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyUnicode_FromString' [-Wunused-function]
    static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject* __Pyx_PyUnicode_FromString(const char* c_str) {
                                   ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:40725:26: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyBytes_Equals' [-Wunused-function]
    static CYTHON_INLINE int __Pyx_PyBytes_Equals(PyObject* s1, PyObject* s2, int equals) {
                             ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:40908:32: warning: unused function '__Pyx_GetItemInt_List_Fast' [-Wunused-function]
    static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject *__Pyx_GetItemInt_List_Fast(PyObject *o, Py_ssize_t i,
                                   ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:40923:32: warning: unused function '__Pyx_GetItemInt_Tuple_Fast' [-Wunused-function]
    static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject *__Pyx_GetItemInt_Tuple_Fast(PyObject *o, Py_ssize_t i,
                                   ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:43162:32: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyInt_From_char' [-Wunused-function]
    static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject* __Pyx_PyInt_From_char(char value) {
                                   ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:43199:48: warning: unused function '__pyx_t_float_complex_from_parts' [-Wunused-function]
        static CYTHON_INLINE __pyx_t_float_complex __pyx_t_float_complex_from_parts(float x, float y) {
                                                   ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:43209:30: warning: unused function '__Pyx_c_eqf' [-Wunused-function]
        static CYTHON_INLINE int __Pyx_c_eqf(__pyx_t_float_complex a, __pyx_t_float_complex b) {
                                 ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:43212:48: warning: unused function '__Pyx_c_sumf' [-Wunused-function]
        static CYTHON_INLINE __pyx_t_float_complex __Pyx_c_sumf(__pyx_t_float_complex a, __pyx_t_float_complex b) {
                                                   ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:43218:48: warning: unused function '__Pyx_c_difff' [-Wunused-function]
        static CYTHON_INLINE __pyx_t_float_complex __Pyx_c_difff(__pyx_t_float_complex a, __pyx_t_float_complex b) {
                                                   ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:43230:48: warning: unused function '__Pyx_c_quotf' [-Wunused-function]
        static CYTHON_INLINE __pyx_t_float_complex __Pyx_c_quotf(__pyx_t_float_complex a, __pyx_t_float_complex b) {
                                                   ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:43237:48: warning: unused function '__Pyx_c_negf' [-Wunused-function]
        static CYTHON_INLINE __pyx_t_float_complex __Pyx_c_negf(__pyx_t_float_complex a) {
                                                   ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:43243:30: warning: unused function '__Pyx_c_is_zerof' [-Wunused-function]
        static CYTHON_INLINE int __Pyx_c_is_zerof(__pyx_t_float_complex a) {
                                 ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:43246:48: warning: unused function '__Pyx_c_conjf' [-Wunused-function]
        static CYTHON_INLINE __pyx_t_float_complex __Pyx_c_conjf(__pyx_t_float_complex a) {
                                                   ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:43260:52: warning: unused function '__Pyx_c_powf' [-Wunused-function]
            static CYTHON_INLINE __pyx_t_float_complex __Pyx_c_powf(__pyx_t_float_complex a, __pyx_t_float_complex b) {
                                                       ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:43319:49: warning: unused function '__pyx_t_double_complex_from_parts' [-Wunused-function]
        static CYTHON_INLINE __pyx_t_double_complex __pyx_t_double_complex_from_parts(double x, double y) {
                                                    ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:43329:30: warning: unused function '__Pyx_c_eq' [-Wunused-function]
        static CYTHON_INLINE int __Pyx_c_eq(__pyx_t_double_complex a, __pyx_t_double_complex b) {
                                 ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:43332:49: warning: unused function '__Pyx_c_sum' [-Wunused-function]
        static CYTHON_INLINE __pyx_t_double_complex __Pyx_c_sum(__pyx_t_double_complex a, __pyx_t_double_complex b) {
                                                    ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:43338:49: warning: unused function '__Pyx_c_diff' [-Wunused-function]
        static CYTHON_INLINE __pyx_t_double_complex __Pyx_c_diff(__pyx_t_double_complex a, __pyx_t_double_complex b) {
                                                    ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:43350:49: warning: unused function '__Pyx_c_quot' [-Wunused-function]
        static CYTHON_INLINE __pyx_t_double_complex __Pyx_c_quot(__pyx_t_double_complex a, __pyx_t_double_complex b) {
                                                    ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:43357:49: warning: unused function '__Pyx_c_neg' [-Wunused-function]
        static CYTHON_INLINE __pyx_t_double_complex __Pyx_c_neg(__pyx_t_double_complex a) {
                                                    ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:43363:30: warning: unused function '__Pyx_c_is_zero' [-Wunused-function]
        static CYTHON_INLINE int __Pyx_c_is_zero(__pyx_t_double_complex a) {
                                 ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:43366:49: warning: unused function '__Pyx_c_conj' [-Wunused-function]
        static CYTHON_INLINE __pyx_t_double_complex __Pyx_c_conj(__pyx_t_double_complex a) {
                                                    ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:43380:53: warning: unused function '__Pyx_c_pow' [-Wunused-function]
            static CYTHON_INLINE __pyx_t_double_complex __Pyx_c_pow(__pyx_t_double_complex a, __pyx_t_double_complex b) {
                                                        ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:35492:32: warning: unused function '__pyx_f_5numpy_PyArray_MultiIterNew1' [-Wunused-function]
    static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject *__pyx_f_5numpy_PyArray_MultiIterNew1(PyObject *__pyx_v_a) {
                                   ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:35542:32: warning: unused function '__pyx_f_5numpy_PyArray_MultiIterNew2' [-Wunused-function]
    static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject *__pyx_f_5numpy_PyArray_MultiIterNew2(PyObject *__pyx_v_a, PyObject *__pyx_v_b) {
                                   ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:35592:32: warning: unused function '__pyx_f_5numpy_PyArray_MultiIterNew3' [-Wunused-function]
    static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject *__pyx_f_5numpy_PyArray_MultiIterNew3(PyObject *__pyx_v_a, PyObject *__pyx_v_b, PyObject *__pyx_v_c) {
                                   ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:35642:32: warning: unused function '__pyx_f_5numpy_PyArray_MultiIterNew4' [-Wunused-function]
    static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject *__pyx_f_5numpy_PyArray_MultiIterNew4(PyObject *__pyx_v_a, PyObject *__pyx_v_b, PyObject *__pyx_v_c, PyObject *__pyx_v_d) {
                                   ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:35692:32: warning: unused function '__pyx_f_5numpy_PyArray_MultiIterNew5' [-Wunused-function]
    static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject *__pyx_f_5numpy_PyArray_MultiIterNew5(PyObject *__pyx_v_a, PyObject *__pyx_v_b, PyObject *__pyx_v_c, PyObject *__pyx_v_d, PyObject *__pyx_v_e) {
                                   ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:36500:27: warning: unused function '__pyx_f_5numpy_set_array_base' [-Wunused-function]
    static CYTHON_INLINE void __pyx_f_5numpy_set_array_base(PyArrayObject *__pyx_v_arr, PyObject *__pyx_v_base) {
                              ^
    bcolz/carray_ext.c:36596:32: warning: unused function '__pyx_f_5numpy_get_array_base' [-Wunused-function]
    static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject *__pyx_f_5numpy_get_array_base(PyArrayObject *__pyx_v_arr) {
                                   ^
    31 warnings generated.
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DHAVE_LZ4=1 -DHAVE_SNAPPY=1 -DHAVE_ZLIB=1 -Ibcolz -Ic-blosc/blosc -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/snappy-1.1.1 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/zlib-1.2.8 -I/Users/choehyeong-gyu/PycharmProjects/CubicHill/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c c-blosc/blosc/blosc.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/c-blosc/blosc/blosc.o
    In file included from c-blosc/blosc/blosc.c:24:
    c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119/lz4.h:179:23: warning: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void* LZ4_createStream();
                          ^
                           void
    c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119/lz4.h:237:29: warning: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void* LZ4_createStreamDecode();
                                ^
                                 void
    2 warnings generated.
    In file included from c-blosc/blosc/blosc.c:24:
    c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119/lz4.h:179:23: warning: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void* LZ4_createStream();
                          ^
                           void
    c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119/lz4.h:237:29: warning: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void* LZ4_createStreamDecode();
                                ^
                                 void
    2 warnings generated.
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DHAVE_LZ4=1 -DHAVE_SNAPPY=1 -DHAVE_ZLIB=1 -Ibcolz -Ic-blosc/blosc -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/snappy-1.1.1 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/zlib-1.2.8 -I/Users/choehyeong-gyu/PycharmProjects/CubicHill/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c c-blosc/blosc/shuffle.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/c-blosc/blosc/shuffle.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DHAVE_LZ4=1 -DHAVE_SNAPPY=1 -DHAVE_ZLIB=1 -Ibcolz -Ic-blosc/blosc -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/snappy-1.1.1 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/zlib-1.2.8 -I/Users/choehyeong-gyu/PycharmProjects/CubicHill/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c c-blosc/blosc/blosclz.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/c-blosc/blosc/blosclz.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DHAVE_LZ4=1 -DHAVE_SNAPPY=1 -DHAVE_ZLIB=1 -Ibcolz -Ic-blosc/blosc -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/snappy-1.1.1 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/zlib-1.2.8 -I/Users/choehyeong-gyu/PycharmProjects/CubicHill/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119/lz4hc.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119/lz4hc.o
    In file included from c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119/lz4hc.c:142:
    c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119/lz4.h:179:23: warning: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void* LZ4_createStream();
                          ^
                           void
    c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119/lz4.h:237:29: warning: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void* LZ4_createStreamDecode();
                                ^
                                 void
    2 warnings generated.
    In file included from c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119/lz4hc.c:142:
    c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119/lz4.h:179:23: warning: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void* LZ4_createStream();
                          ^
                           void
    c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119/lz4.h:237:29: warning: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void* LZ4_createStreamDecode();
                                ^
                                 void
    2 warnings generated.
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DHAVE_LZ4=1 -DHAVE_SNAPPY=1 -DHAVE_ZLIB=1 -Ibcolz -Ic-blosc/blosc -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/snappy-1.1.1 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/zlib-1.2.8 -I/Users/choehyeong-gyu/PycharmProjects/CubicHill/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119/lz4.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119/lz4.o
    In file included from c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119/lz4.c:163:
    c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119/lz4.h:179:23: warning: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void* LZ4_createStream();
                          ^
                           void
    c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119/lz4.h:237:29: warning: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void* LZ4_createStreamDecode();
                                ^
                                 void
    2 warnings generated.
    In file included from c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119/lz4.c:163:
    c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119/lz4.h:179:23: warning: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void* LZ4_createStream();
                          ^
                           void
    c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119/lz4.h:237:29: warning: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void* LZ4_createStreamDecode();
                                ^
                                 void
    2 warnings generated.
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DHAVE_LZ4=1 -DHAVE_SNAPPY=1 -DHAVE_ZLIB=1 -Ibcolz -Ic-blosc/blosc -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/snappy-1.1.1 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/zlib-1.2.8 -I/Users/choehyeong-gyu/PycharmProjects/CubicHill/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c c-blosc/internal-complibs/snappy-1.1.1/snappy-stubs-internal.cc -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/c-blosc/internal-complibs/snappy-1.1.1/snappy-stubs-internal.o
    warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-std=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
    c-blosc/internal-complibs/snappy-1.1.1/snappy-stubs-internal.cc:29:10: fatal error: 'algorithm' file not found
    #include <algorithm>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning and 1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

EDIT 2 after trying CXXFLAGS="-std=libc++" CFLAGS="-std=libc++" CC="clang++"  pip install zipline:
It still failed.

```
  Failed building wheel for bcolz
  Running setup.py clean for bcolz
Failed to build bcolz
Installing collected packages: bcolz, zipline
  Running setup.py install for bcolz ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/choehyeong-gyu/PycharmProjects/CubicHill/venv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/n5/yqd1_zh15xz55dy2qzsjxzfr0000gn/T/pip-build-beuburui/bcolz/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/n5/yqd1_zh15xz55dy2qzsjxzfr0000gn/T/pip-b2puzll6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/choehyeong-gyu/PycharmProjects/CubicHill/venv/bin/../include/site/python3.6/bcolz:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz
    copying bcolz/py2help_tests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz
    copying bcolz/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz
    copying bcolz/toplevel.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz
    copying bcolz/ctable.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz
    copying bcolz/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz
    copying bcolz/utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz
    copying bcolz/chunked_eval.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz
    copying bcolz/defaults.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz
    copying bcolz/attrs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz
    copying bcolz/py2help.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz
    copying bcolz/arrayprint.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz/tests
    copying bcolz/tests/test_ndcarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz/tests
    copying bcolz/tests/test_carray_objects.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz/tests
    copying bcolz/tests/test_attrs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz/tests
    copying bcolz/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz/tests
    copying bcolz/tests/all.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz/tests
    copying bcolz/tests/common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz/tests
    copying bcolz/tests/test_queries.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz/tests
    copying bcolz/tests/test_ctable.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz/tests
    copying bcolz/tests/test_carray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz/tests
    copying bcolz/carray_ext.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz
    running build_ext
    skipping 'bcolz/carray_ext.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'bcolz.carray_ext' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/c-blosc
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/c-blosc/blosc
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/c-blosc/internal-complibs
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/c-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/c-blosc/internal-complibs/snappy-1.1.1
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/c-blosc/internal-complibs/zlib-1.2.8
    clang++ -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -std=libc++ -DHAVE_LZ4=1 -DHAVE_SNAPPY=1 -DHAVE_ZLIB=1 -Ibcolz -Ic-blosc/blosc -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/snappy-1.1.1 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r119 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/zlib-1.2.8 -I/Users/choehyeong-gyu/PycharmProjects/CubicHill/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c bcolz/carray_ext.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/bcolz/carray_ext.o -std=libc++
    clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
    error: invalid value 'libc++' in '-std=libc++'
    note: use 'c++98' or 'c++03' for 'ISO C++ 1998 with amendments' standard
    note: use 'gnu++98' or 'gnu++03' for 'ISO C++ 1998 with amendments and GNU extensions' standard
    note: use 'c++11' for 'ISO C++ 2011 with amendments' standard
    note: use 'gnu++11' for 'ISO C++ 2011 with amendments and GNU extensions' standard
    note: use 'c++14' for 'ISO C++ 2014 with amendments' standard
    note: use 'gnu++14' for 'ISO C++ 2014 with amendments and GNU extensions' standard
    note: use 'c++17' for 'ISO C++ 2017 with amendments' standard
    note: use 'gnu++17' for 'ISO C++ 2017 with amendments and GNU extensions' standard
    note: use 'c++2a' for 'Working draft for ISO C++ 2020' standard
    note: use 'gnu++2a' for 'Working draft for ISO C++ 2020 with GNU extensions' standard
    error: command 'clang++' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/choehyeong-gyu/PycharmProjects/CubicHill/venv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/n5/yqd1_zh15xz55dy2qzsjxzfr0000gn/T/pip-build-beuburui/bcolz/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/n5/yqd1_zh15xz55dy2qzsjxzfr0000gn/T/pip-b2puzll6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/choehyeong-gyu/PycharmProjects/CubicHill/venv/bin/../include/site/python3.6/bcolz" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/n5/yqd1_zh15xz55dy2qzsjxzfr0000gn/T/pip-build-beuburui/bcolz/
```

EDIT 3 :

Here are the packages that the pip install command is installing.

```
Collecting zipline
Requirement already satisfied: Mako>=1.0.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: alembic>=0.7.7 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=4.0.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Collecting bcolz<1,>=0.12.1 (from zipline)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6c/8b/1ffa01f872cac36173c5eb95b58c01040d8d25f1b242c48577f4104cd3ab/bcolz-0.12.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: toolz>=0.8.2 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: cyordereddict>=0.2.2 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: intervaltree>=2.1.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-file>=1.4.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>18.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.9.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: multipledispatch>=0.4.8 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx<2.0,>=1.9.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy>=1.0.8 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython>=0.25.2 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: sortedcontainers>=1.4.4 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=4.0.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas-datareader>=0.2.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.4.2 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: patsy>=0.4.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=7.1.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: contextlib2>=0.4.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: empyrical>=0.5.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: statsmodels>=0.6.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: Logbook>=0.12.5 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: bottleneck>=1.0.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: lru-dict>=1.1.4 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas<=0.22,>=0.18.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: trading-calendars>=1.0.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.17.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2016.4 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: numexpr>=2.6.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: tables>=3.3.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: python-editor>=0.3 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from alembic>=0.7.7->zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas-datareader>=0.2.1->zipline)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas-datareader>=0.2.1->zipline)
Building wheels for collected packages: bcolz
```

EDIT 4 :

```
error: invalid argument '-std=gnu++11' not allowed with 'C'
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/choehyeong-gyu/PycharmProjects/CubicHill/venv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/n5/yqd1_zh15xz55dy2qzsjxzfr0000gn/T/pip-build-leowqoun/bcolz/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/n5/yqd1_zh15xz55dy2qzsjxzfr0000gn/T/pip-r5iqy2oy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/choehyeong-gyu/PycharmProjects/CubicHill/venv/bin/../include/site/python3.6/bcolz" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/n5/yqd1_zh15xz55dy2qzsjxzfr0000gn/T/pip-build-leowqoun/bcolz/
```

Comment: Please post the complete error trace.

Comment: @hoefling I've posted the last part of the error.

Comment: Can you post all the output up to the pip install command? It would be useful to see which packages is pip installing in your machine.

Comment: Try `CXXFLAGS="-std=libc++" CFLAGS="-std=libc++" pip install zipline`; you may also need to add `CC="clang++"`. Can't test it myself, don't have a macbook anymore.

Comment: @hoefling I've tried both, without any success.. I've additionally posted the errors of trying `CXXFLAGS="-std=libc++" CFLAGS="-std=libc++" CC="clang++ pip install zipline`.

Comment: @dopstar I've posted the installed packages on EDIT 3

Comment: Try the suggested standards, e.g. `CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" CFLAGS="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" CC="clang++" pip install zipline` etc.

Comment: Actually, it looks like `libc++` is now the default one on newer MacOS versions, so you can omit the `-stdlib=libc++` flag; `CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11" CFLAGS="-std=c++11" CC="clang++" pip install zipline` should be enough. If errors occur, play with standards, e.g. try `CXXFLAGS="-std=gnu++11" CFLAGS="-std=gnu++11" CC="clang++" pip install zipline` etc.

Comment: @hoefling I've tried both but nothing seems to work.. Thanks for your help though

Comment: Try using `gcc` instead of `clang`: `CXXFLAGS="-std=gnu++11" CFLAGS="-std=gnu++11" CC="gcc" pip install zipline`. If you don't have `gcc` available (`which gcc` returns nothing or error), install the xcode command line tools first: `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: @hoefling I already had xcode installed. And the command above does not work as well..

Comment: Can you post the error message from the last command?

Comment: @hoefling I've posted it on EDIT 4. Thank you

Comment: I've resolved(?) the issue by using conda environment and using the conda command instead of the pip command

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
> export DISABLE_BCOLZ_AVX2=true
```

Then try again

```
pip install zipline
```

My environment:
Ubuntu 20.04
Python 3.6 & 3.6 DEV

Reference:
https://github.com/Blosc/bcolz/issues/398#issuecomment-698748897

Answer (score 0):

add

> export CPATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1

to you ~/.profile

execute

> source ~/.profile

then install again

Comment: I succeed after doing this

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and could only resolve it by disabling the *avx2* and *sse2* compiler flags.

```
export DISABLE_BCOLZ_AVX2=true DISABLE_BCOLZ_SSE2=true
```

SSE2 and AVX2 are instruction sets only found in Intel and AMD CPUs, also known as x86 architecture. The dependency bcolz of the library zipline takes advantage of this architecture. Therefore, SSE2 and AVX2 are enabled by default. To build wheel for bcolz for ARM architecture, one needs to disable x86 specific instructions.

Comment: please add more explanation for others to understand your answer better

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Updated my answer for better clarity.